# ESLint configuration in .eslintrc is invalid: - Unexpected top-level property "import/no-extraneous-dependencies"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, grommet

I was writing a code to access webcam, click a picture through my react app or browse and upload the picture from your files. For using react-html5-camera-phot and grommet [I was getting these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqA2W.png), Basically the error was **import/no-extraneous-dependencies** error.

For resolving this, I ran the suggested commands but the issue persisted and I kept getting the same error.

Therefore to remove these errors i went through stack overflow, and got a solution that suggested to post **import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": false, "optionalDependencies": false, "peerDependencies": false}]** in my .eslintrc file. I posted this and now I am getting this error:

**ESLint configuration in .eslintrc is invalid:
- Unexpected top-level property "import/no-extraneous-dependencies".**

I tried resolving this error too but could not find anything helpful. Please if you can tell me what I am doing wrong, itll be very helpful! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put under rules object:

```
"rules": {
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error",  {"devDependencies": true}],
    ...
}
```